# Query to get Windows format Timezone name like US Eastern Standard Time as output in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

In SQL server, is there any query to get the windows format Time zone name of current server like India Standard Time or US Eastern Standard Time.

By Using SELECT SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() , it's getting Time zone offset value but requirement is to get Time zone name.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMEZONE()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/current-timezone-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: thanks for providing link. but it is mentioned it applies to Azure SQL database  but not to SQL server on premise.

Comment: Did you look at `SELECT * FROM sys.time_zone_info;`? Though if all you have is the current offset in minutes/hours, you're going to have a hard time reliably selecting the right one, because some offsets map to many different time zone names.

Comment: Let's turn this around. Why would it matter what the server timezone is set to? How is that information useful to a client application? Surely the client app would either display values in local time or GMT (or whatever timezone the **user** prefers).

Answer (score 0):

Found this on [SQL Authority](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/02/15/sql-server-get-current-timezone-name-in-sql-server/)

```
DECLARE @TimeZone VARCHAR(50);
EXEC MASTER.dbo.xp_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation',
'TimeZoneKeyName',@TimeZone OUT;
SELECT @TimeZone as 'Current TimeZone';
```